# Listing files in directory: weird output

Tags: windows, command-line

I was trying to list files in some directory, but I am
getting weird results.

This is command I type in command prompt: `dir *t.*`

This is result:

```
c:\test\1.1.1990.txt
c:\test\1.31.1990.txt
c:\test\1.txttxt
c:\test\11.11.2007.txtGif
c:\test\12.1.1990.txt
c:\test\12.31.1990.txt
c:\test\2.tGift
c:\test\2.txtGif
c:\test\5bbb.exeTxt
c:\test\test.txt
```

9th output is particularly weird: `5bbb.exeTxt`,
why did I get this result considering my query?
(now that I look at it most results seem weird?)
e.g., why 2nd?

Can someone please explain?

I will need to use [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which works in the same way I guess, that is why I am interested.

> **Related: [List files in folder which match pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739767/list-files-in-folder-which-match-pattern)** (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Are you sure you're not making a typo on this? Unless I'm mis-reading, the only thing I see that actually matches your query is the last item on the list. Everything else (mostly) seems to match appropriate output for `dir *.t*` (exception being the second-to-last item, which you've also noted as strange).

Comment: @Iszi: That's why I am confused. Can you recreate this problem locally at your place? Here is the screen: http://postimg.org/image/mjl7yjhed/

Comment: Duplicated on my end. Very odd. For a minute, I thought it might have something to do with short filename mappings, but the results of `dir /x` don't show anything that would explain it. Which version of Windows are you using? PowerShell might be a better tool for whatever you're trying to do here. (I tested the same command in PowerShell - where `dir` is an alias to `Get-ChildItem`, and the results were as expected.)

Comment: @Iszi: I need to (probably) use it via C# method as I mentioned ..

Comment: I'm getting that [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/152399) feeling again. I suggest opening a separate question, with the description of your *actual* problem. Firstly, your presumption that *anything* in C# - a relatively new programming language - will work the same way as a user-level command in a console as archaic as `CMD` is *very* flawed. If there's any relation to be made between C# and a common Windows CLI it would be to PowerShell, but that's really still going about things the wrong way.

Comment: @Iszi: that C# method is using WIndows API which is same as commands I type in cmd, I tested mostly they yield similar results - anyway that is not my main problem now. My main problem is: behaviour of this pattern matching which seems unpredictable

Comment: Your problem now is that you're trying to assess the behavior of one thing by testing the behavior of an almost completely unrelated thing. Yes, they may both use the same API but unless you can see the code that's working behind them you don't know *how* they're using the API. Two programs could use the same API but take and parse input in completely different manners before that input is passed to the API. If you want to test usage of the GetFiles method properly, you'll need to actually *use* the GetFiles method instead of trying these proxies.

Comment: @Iszi: I know, someone said it used same API(who seems to know that). Anyway they showed same results on some tests. I know what you mean. But that cmd is giving strange results is concerning me(see some new comments I did to dsolimano)

Comment: What problem are you *really* trying to solve, though? This is not a forum for general discussion of a mutating problem. You've stated that you had odd output with `dir *t.*`, and a solution has been given for that. If you're trying to figure out why `dir *t` produces unexpected results, that's a *completely* different issue. Further, unless there's some particular reason you're still sticking with `dir` that you haven't mentioned, none of this appears to even address your *real* problem which is how to properly use and judge the output of the GetFiles method.

Comment: @Iszi: I gave you answer below.

Comment: To more directly test the GetFiles method, you could use PowerShell. This allows direct access to .NET Framework objects which are based on C#. It can be called from powerShell using the syntax `[IO.Directory]::GetFiles('Path')` or `[IO.Directory]::GetFiles('Path','SearchPattern)` or `[IO.Directory]::GetFiles('Path','SearchPattern','SearchOption')` as described in the documentation linked in your question.

Comment: After looking around and thinking about it some more, I believe the problem you're having with `dir *t.*` may have something to do with an implied trailing dot at the end of filenames. e.g.: `Filename.txt` is equivalent to `Filename.txt.` and therefore `dir *t.* would match any file with a "t" immediately before, or exactly at the end, of the file extension. However, this is just a hunch (domain names, and perhaps some other filesystem/Internet resources have similar behavior) and I'm having a hard time finding documentation to back it up.

Comment: Did some testing which appears to confirm my theory, though I still can't find documentation yet. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because of the behavior mentioned in [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) (warning - not actual documentation).

> For example, if your pattern ends in .*, the .* is ignored. Without
>   this rule, the pattern *.* would match only files that contained a
>   dot, which would break probably 90% of all the batch files on the
>   planet, as well as everybody's muscle memory, since everybody running
>   Windows NT 3.1 grew up in a world where *.* meant all files.

Your pattern is `*t.*`, which gets changed to, I'm assuming, `*t`, which then matches `5bbb.exeTxt`.  I'm not sure how `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` works, why not just test it?

Looks like perhaps short names are also matched, or the first three characters of the extension.

```
G:\junk\filetest>dir
 Volume in drive G is Extended2
 Volume Serial Number is 3E2F-7A67

 Directory of G:\junk\filetest

09/09/2014  10:01 AM    <DIR>          .
09/09/2014  10:01 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/09/2014  09:59 AM                 6 test.txtR
09/09/2014  10:01 AM                 2 test.txtrrr
               2 File(s)              8 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  162,957,000,704 bytes free

G:\junk\filetest>dir *.txt
 Volume in drive G is Extended2
 Volume Serial Number is 3E2F-7A67

 Directory of G:\junk\filetest

09/09/2014  09:59 AM                 6 test.txtR
09/09/2014  10:01 AM                 2 test.txtrrr
               2 File(s)              8 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  162,957,000,704 bytes free

G:\junk\filetest>dir /x *.txt
 Volume in drive G is Extended2
 Volume Serial Number is 3E2F-7A67

 Directory of G:\junk\filetest

09/09/2014  09:59 AM                 6 TEST~1.TXT   test.txtR
09/09/2014  10:01 AM                 2 TEST~2.TXT   test.txtrrr
               2 File(s)              8 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  162,957,000,704 bytes free
```

Comment: @dsolimano: how do you explain the 4th output then?

Comment: @dsolimano: here's another weird output: http://postimg.org/image/dtb1r1ck7/, maybe you can explain this?

Comment: I cannot!  Perhaps it's matching a short name?  Or perhaps it just matches the first three characters of the extension.  I'll post a test I just ran.

Comment: @dsolimano: first three characters of extension maybe - that would explain Output Nr 4 in my latest screenshot? I am not sure what you tried to show in your sample... Maybe this way of pattern matching is not very reliable?

Comment: @georgem Type `dir *t /x` and it will explain your latest output issue.

Comment: @Iszi: it doesn't? Is there some guide which explains this outputs? I think regex is more accurate and I will switch to that. Users will type this pattern in my program and I don't want them to get unexpected results.

Comment: Again, you're using the wrong test method. You should *not* be using `CMD` or `dir` - which are *programs in their own right* - to gauge expectations for the behavior of lower-level functions like Windows API calls. The command I gave you explains the output because it reveals the Short Filename for listed objects. For backwards compatibility, the `dir` command includes Short Filenames in is searches (0111120~1.TXT here). This is *not* something that is universal to all similar commands (test `dir *t` in PowerShell for comparison) and therefore *cannot* be assumed to be native API behavior.

Comment: @Iszi: I am getting SAME output using GetFiles method

Comment: If you're already using the GetFiles method directly, why bother testing with `dir` then? Since this is really a question about API behavior, I suggest rephrasing it as such - with demonstration of your testing methods that use GetFiles *directly* - and posting on [so].

Comment: @Iszi: I did it and they mentioned it uses same Windows API as command line!. I think I will use Regex. Because the way this API pattern matching works seems unpredictable? Or I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: @georgem I would agree that doing your own globing is almost certainly the way to go if you are coding it yourself. If this is a web app you wouldn't want to allow end users to be able to enter their own RegEx expressions though. If this is a desktop application or web administration interface then it would probably be ok.

Comment: @krowe: my problem is CMD output seems unpredictable for me? am I doing something wrong? is there some doc for it? (otherwise yes I will go for regex)

Comment: @Iszi, he tried to post on Stack Overflow and got shot down and told to post on SuperUser.  I followed the question over from there.

Comment: @georgem OK, well I actually wrote a script which could solve this pretty well a while back: https://gist.github.com/krowe/da2a6b021ac891f8e3be Maybe that is more like what you wanted?

Comment: @dsolimano Yeah, I'm on the question over there now and it's really a completely different question - the behavior he's asking about there is *not* the behavior asked about here. Still, I'm a bit confused as to why they'd send him here for a question about APIs and programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think @dsolimano (and his source, Raymond Chen) got pretty close to your problem but perhaps don't quite have the right explanation. After some thinking and searching and testing, although I've yet to come up with actual documentation to back this up, I believe I've come to a reasonably accurate conclusion.

My hypothesis is based on somewhat related behavior in domain names and some other named computer resources. With domain names, there's actually an implied trailing dot at the end. Therefore `www.superuser.com` is actually `www.superuser.com.`. My conclusion, after some testing, is that the Windows API (if not the filesystem itself) uses the same convention for filenames.

Think about all the file names you gave which matched your result. If you consider that 8.3 filenames are included in searches, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com./en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and assume that long filenames with a trailing dot *and* 8.3 filenames with a trailing dot are also included, you'll see that *every one* of those files matches by at least one version of its filename. (Remember that the `*` wildcard is a placeholder which represents "any number of characters, or no characters".)

- `c:\test\1.1.1990.txt` matches as `1.1.1990.txt.` or `111990~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\1.31.1990.txt` matches as `1.31.1990.txt.` or `131199~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\1.txttxt` matches as `1.txttxt.` or `1956B~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\11.11.2007.txtGif` matches as `111120~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\12.1.1990.txt` matches as `12.1.1990.txt.` or `12199~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\12.31.1990.txt` matches as `12.31.1990.txt` or `123119~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\2.tGift` matches as `2.tGift.`
- `c:\test\2.txtGif` matches as `2BEFD~1.TXT.`
- `c:\test\5bbb.exeTxt` matches as `5bbb.exeTxt.`
- `c:\test\test.txt` matches as `test.txt` or `test.txt.`

You can test this by creating a series of test files in `C:\test` as described below, and running `dir *t.*` against it again.

1. A file with an extension ending in "t".
2. A file with name ending in "t".
3. A file with an extension longer than three letters with the third letter in the extension being "t".
4. Some files which match more than one of the above criteria.
5. A file with name ending in "t", and no extension at all.
6. Some files which do not meet any of the above criteria.

You should see, as I have, that `dir *t.*` will only return files which fall into categories 1-5 above. Files in category 6 will be excluded. You can also thest the `GetFiles` method more directly against the same files with PowerShell, using the below command, and you should see the same results.

```
[IO.Directory]::GetFiles('C:\test','*t.*')
```

Comment: I will study your theory. But in my case  users will type the matching pattern. Hence, I need to be exactly sure what the output be, I can't rely on "Suprises". Considering that, do you still recommend using Directory.GetFiles method?

Comment: @georgem Honestly, I'm neither a programmer nor do I know exactly what your requirements are. So, I really can't give you a good answer for that. I will say that PowerShell's `Get-ChildItems` command appears to have more "normal" behavior, and it does support RegEx. So, you might want to look into how it does its job and try to work from there.